# Drawing a positioning graph in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to do some graph similar to the following in TiKZ (I'm a very basic user) and I'm having some problems:

[image: Example]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{High Price};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{High Quality};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have gotten to obtain the axis (which are black, just normal axis). However, I don't know how to place the labels in the right position.

Furthermore, I need to write other names instead of Brand A, Brand B, etc. These names are longer and I would like to write them with a break in two lines for not using too much horizontal space. The letters do not have to be blue with white filling (just the regular LaTeX font).

Comment: Can you show what you try so far? Developing code from scratch is like request `do-it-instead-me` ...

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, sorry! I just added the code so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 line/.style = {draw=blue!50!gray!25, line width=3mm, 
                {Triangle[length=6mm,width=9mm]}-{Triangle[length=6mm,width=9mm]}},
brand/.style = {font=\Large\bfseries, text=blue!20!black!60, 
                align=left, anchor=west}
                    ]
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[line] (-5,0) node[left]{Low Price} 
                    --(5,0) node[right]{High Price};
\draw[line] (0,-5) node[below]{Low Quality}
                    --(0,5) node[above]{High Quality};
%
\node[brand] at (-5,-3) {Brand E};
\node[brand] at (-3,-2) {Brand D};
\node[brand] at ( 1, 1) {Brand B};
\node[brand] at ( 3, 3) {Brand A\\ Brand C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Images is similar to picture you provide, however differences are in shadows of axes and in fonts for text in picture:

[image]

**Eddit:** shadows of coordinate axes can be simulated with drawing them twice, slightly shifted:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 line/.style = {draw=#1, line width=3mm,
                {Triangle[length=6mm,width=9mm]}-{Triangle[length=6mm,width=9mm]},
                },
brand/.style = {font=\Large\bfseries, text=blue!20!black!60,
                align=left, anchor=west}
                    ]
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[line=gray,yshift=-1pt,xshift=1pt]  (-5,0) edge (5,0)
                                            (0,-5)  to  (0,5);
\draw[line=blue!50!gray!25]
    (-5,0) node[left]{Low Price} --(5,0) node[right]{High Price};
\draw[line=blue!50!gray!25]
    (0,-5) node[below]{Low Quality} --(0,5) node[above]{High Quality};
%
\node[brand] at (-5,-3) {Brand E};
\node[brand] at (-3,-2) {Brand D};
\node[brand] at ( 1, 1) {Brand B};
\node[brand] at ( 3, 3) {Brand A\\ Brand C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]